# UnitTest on MVC controller HttpStatusCode not equal

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm doing a unit test on a simple controller checking that when a null ID is passed in that it returns a 400 code. However when I test this the result does not come back as being equal to a 400 error code.

My code:

```
int? nullID = null;
var edit = controller.Edit(nullID) as ActionResult;

var result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, null);

Assert.AreEqual(edit, result);
```

When I debug the test I get the expected result seen here:

Edit Result:

[image: Edit Result]

Expected Result:

[image: Expected Result]

Where am I going wrong on this?

Comment: I'm not seeing what you mean, your edit is of type HttpStatusCodeResult and has statuscode 400 with no description, just as your result that you specify in your test. What's not working as it should?
Or is your assert failing? in that case i'd say that the .Equals implementation from HttpStatusCodeResult is not dooing what you expect it to do

Comment: When I assert that edit and result are equal in my test that fails and I cant understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the equals method of HttpStatusCodeResult is looking at the reference key, i tested your setup and my assert fails as well. Asserting the statuscodes itself however does work. see example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{

  var resultOne = new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, null);
  var resultTwo = new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, null);

  // Assert
  Assert.AreEqual(resultOne.StatusCode, resultTwo.StatusCode);

  Assert.AreEqual(resultOne, resultTwo);
}
```

The `Assert.AreEqual(resultOne.StatusCode, resultTwo.StatusCode);` succeeds while the `Assert.AreEqual(resultOne, resultTwo);` fails

**update**

See the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) about HttpStatusCodeResult here you can see that the equals implemenation is Inherited from Object and therefor does not anything with the properties in the object, but only looks at the reference keys

Answer (score 4):

`Assert.AreEqual(a,b)` is the same as `Assert.IsTrue(Object.Equals(a,b))`

[`HttpStatusCodeResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult(v=vs.118).aspx) does not implement `Equals` so the call goes to the default `Object.Equals()` which in turn defaults to [`Object.RefrenceEquals(a,b))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.118).aspx)

> If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object) method tests for reference equality, and a call to the Equals(Object) method is equivalent to a call to the ReferenceEquals method. Reference equality means that the object variables that are compared refer to the same object.